# How can I swap focus when I run Python code in VSCode without using the mouse?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run a code without debug (Ctrl+F5) the cursor stays in the terminal. How do I change the settings so that the focus stays in the editor after running the code?

Comment: Why tag with `visual-studio` and `visual-studio-2015` if you have a question about `visual-studio-code`?

Comment: Thank you for your observation, I have changed it

Answer (score 2):

Title question: "How can I swap focus [...] without using the mouse?"

Answer: Use command "View: Focus First Editor Group", which by default is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Body question: "how [...] after running any code the focus stays in the editor ?"

Answer: One way is, in `launch.json`, to set `console` to [`externalTerminal`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_console).  Then the output will appear in a new window, and after you press a key to dismiss it, the VSCode focus will remain where it was when you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

If you don't have a `launch.json` file yet, VSCode will make one for you with "Debug → Open Configurations".  Here is the `launch.json` my VSCode created when I did that, and I then subsequently edited:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      //"console": "integratedTerminal"
      "console": "externalTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```